# How can I retrieve the patches associated with a certain file?

Tags: git, version-control, patch

Having cloned a git repo I want to retrieve all commits associated with a certain file, printed out each one in a separate file.

This must have something to do with git log or git format patch.

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `git rev-list` to retrieve sha1 of all commit touching a path:

```
$ git rev-list --all -- path
```

This will give you a list sha1 of each commit that touch that path. If you want the commit message and patches, you can use `git log`:

```
$ git log --all -- path
$ git log --all -p -- path
```

Comment: To get them all in separate files, the easiest thing is probably something like: `git rev-list [--all] -- <path> | while read c; do git log -1 -p $c -- <path> > $c.patch; done`. If you want to be able to tell what order they go in, you might want to add a counter on there like format-patch does. (Unfortunately, format-patch doesn't seem to be able to do patches only for single files.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the changes made to a file at each commit you can use the '[whatchanged](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-whatchanged.html)' command

```
git whatchanged [options] <file>
```

Check out this [tutorial for creating and applying patches](http://ariejan.net/2009/10/26/how-to-create-and-apply-a-patch-with-git/)